# How would one use a [Wicket] ListView with a form?

Tags: wicket

I have added a `Form` on submit of which I have to add more wicket controls like Labels, textfields and button with an Ajex Link. But not able to get the correct HTML. Can anyone please help me to get rid of it ?

**voucherPanel.html**

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <wicket:panel>
    <div class="form-block">
      <div wicket:id="form">
        <wicket:message key="lbl.vouchercode" />
        <div wicket:id="list">
          <input wicket:id="word" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div wicket:id="vouchercode"></div>
      <button wicket:id="submit"><wicket:message key="submitText"/></button>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

**voucherPanel.java**

```
public class VoucherPanel extends Panel
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public VoucherPanel(final String id)
  {
    super(id);

    final TextField<String> voucherCodeField = new TextField<String>("vouchercode", Model.of(""));
    voucherCodeField.setRequired(true);

    final Button button = new Button("submit");

    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form")
    {

      @Override
      protected void onSubmit()
      {

              numberOfFields = new ArrayList<String>();

              int noOfVocuhers = getNoOfAllowedVoucher();// just returing the number
              for (int i = 0; i < noOfVocuhers; i++) {
                numberOfFields.add(new String(""));
            }

            add(new ListView<Object>("list", numberOfFields) {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem<Object> item) {
                    final String word = (String) item.getModelObject();
                    System.out.println( "word   =" +word );
                    TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String>("word",  Model.of(""));
                    textField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                    item.add(textField);
                }
            });

        }
      }
    };

    add(form);

    form.add(voucherCodeField);
    form.add(button);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any code snippet with your efforts so far and telling us where are you stuck would also be useful. Also, it's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to dynamically add elements to a `ListView` when the form is submitted? By the way, take a look at [Dynamically add components to ListView in Wicket](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114351/851811).

Comment: Can anyone help me to get rid of the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You're trying to assign a `Textfield` to a `<div>` element (`voucherCode`), you need `<input type="text">` instead.
2. You need to add `list` to your form right away, `onSubmit` is too late. Just set it outside, similar to `button` and call `myListView.setList` when submitting the form.

These are the two things I spotted... if you still have problems please let us know about the error messages you get.